# Why does std::array::begin return a pointer instead of an iterator?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++17, stdarray

I am trying to build a nested iterator template and relied on iterators having various traits like `value_type`. But as it turns out, not all STL types even return iterators with those traits. For instance:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using iterator_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().begin());

static_assert(std::is_same_v<iterator_t<std::array<int, 3>>, int*>);
```

This code compiles and shows that the actual type of the array iterator is `int*`. In that case, how can I still access traits such as `value_type` etc?

Comment: You can access traits using `std::iterator_traits<iterator_t>`. They are specialized for pointer types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard doesn't specify how the iterator should be implemented and what the exact type it should be.
It just says that [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a *[ContiguousContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousContainer)*, meaning that its iterator is *[ContiguousIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator)*.

In fact, pointers like `int*` do satisfy the requirements of the iterator of [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), so it's quite legitimate for implementation.

You can use [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) to get the `value_type`, like:

```cpp
std::iterator_traits<std::iterator_t<std::array<int, 3>>>::value_type
```

It works with pointers too.

Answer (score 6):

`int*` *is* an iterator as it satisfies all the requirements necessary of an iterator.

Informally:

1. You can *deference* it (unless it's past the final element of the array).
2. You can *increment* it (as it's a pointer in an array).
3. You can *copy* `int*` to another `int*`.
4. You can call `std::swap` with `int*` as the types.